# loop thru 2D-arrays in Python to get the different values

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-loops

I have two 2d-arrays, they have different length.

```
target = 
[('CRC_SRC', '2021-08-02 02:22:43.0'),
('CRC_RISK_LIB', '2021-08-02 02:22:42.0'),
('CRC_QST_LIB', '2021-08-02 02:22:42.0'),
('CRC_PROD_LIB', '2021-08-02 02:22:41.0'),
('CRC_TOOL_LIB', '2021-08-02 02:22:44.0'),
('CRC_MAP', '2021-07-26 02:31:56.0'),
('sample_table', '2021-07-31 02:31:56.0'),]

source = 
[('CRC_SRC', '2021-08-12 02:22:43.0'),
('CRC_RISK_LIB', '2021-08-02 02:22:42.0'),
('CRC_QST_LIB', '2021-08-12 02:22:42.0'),
('CRC_PROD_LIB', '2021-08-10 02:22:41.0'),
('CRC_TOOL_LIB', '2021-08-02 02:22:44.0'),
('CRC_DEFN_LV', '2021-07-26 02:31:56.0'),
('sample_table', '2021-07-25 02:31:56.0'),
('another table', '2021-07-29 03:31:56.0')]
```

My goal is to find the different and the same values. I came up with a nested loop to do part of the job

```
for i in range(len(target)):
    for j in range(len(source)):
        if target[i] == source[j]:
            print('they are equal in name and timestamp: ', target[i])
        elif target[i][0] == source[j][0] and target[i][1] < source[j][1]:
            print('target timestamp is less than source timestamp: ', target[i], source[j])
        elif target[i][0] == source[j][0] and target[i][1] > source[j][1]:
            print('source timestamp is less than target timestamp: ', target[i], source[j])
```

output is:

```
they are equal in name and timestamp:  ('CRC_RISK_LIB', '2021-08-02 02:22:42.0')
target timestamp is less than source timestamp:  ('CRC_QST_LIB', '2021-08-02 02:22:42.0') ('CRC_QST_LIB', '2021-08-12 02:22:42.0')
target timestamp is less than source timestamp:  ('CRC_PROD_LIB', '2021-08-02 02:22:41.0') ('CRC_PROD_LIB', '2021-08-10 02:22:41.0')
they are equal in name and timestamp:  ('CRC_TOOL_LIB', '2021-08-02 02:22:44.0')
source timestamp is less than target timestamp:  ('sample_table', '2021-07-31 02:31:56.0') ('sample_table', '2021-07-25 02:31:56.0')
```

Desired output would ADD the following :

```
source name is not in target name: ('CRC_DEFN_LV', '2021-07-26 02:31:56.0') ('another table', '2021-07-29 03:31:56.0')
```

How do I find the different names in two lists regardless of the difference in timestamp? Please advise, thanks. I tried set methods in python, such as -, | or ^, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution you can give it a try,

```
source_, target_ = dict(source), dict(target)

diff_ = " ".join(f"({i}, {source_[i]})" for i in source_.keys() - target_.keys())

print(
    "source name is not in target name:", diff_
)
```

---

```
source name is not in target name: (CRC_DEFN_LV, 2021-07-26 02:31:56.0) (CR_SRC, 2021-08-12 02:22:43.0) (another table, 2021-07-29 03:31:56.0)
```

Comment: this is a nice way to do it. Thanks. Is there a way I can incorporate to the nested for loop?